# Как передать ссылки на объекты в классы сервлетов?

Tags: java, ооп, servlet

У меня есть несколько сервлетов которые используют один объект для работы с базой. Но я не знаю как мне передать туда этот объект так как объекты самих сервлетов tomcat создает и вызывает сам, то не понятно как туда что-то передать.

Вот два сервлета которые должны работать с одним объектом отвечающим за работу с базой:

```
public class AddUserServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private DBJointPool db; // Как передать этот объект в класс?

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        db.somethingToDoWithDatabaseConnectionPool();

    }
}

public class DeleteUserServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private DBJointPool db; // Как передать этот объект в класс?

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        db.somethingToDoWithDatabaseConnectionPool();

    }
}
```

Как это решается учитывая что я использую `JDBCDriver` без фрэймворков?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте внедрение зависимостей.

О стандартной CDI из спецификаций Java EE уже говорил Вам как-то.

Есть ещё Spring Framework (конкурент Java EE), особо популярный среди россиянских программистов. Со своим внедрением (можно сказать что как раз с него и пошло всё внедрение).

На низком уровне (которым так же пользуются и все фремвёрки-внедренцы) общие объекты хранятся в сессии.
Сессию можно получить так:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
```

Где request как не трудно догадаться - это HttpServletRequest

Далее у сессии имеется мешок, в который можно складывать что угодно и потом извлекать когда угодно. Объект ассоциируется с ключом. И называется атрибутом сессии.

Сохранить в сессию:

```
Object object = new Object();
session.setAttribute("key", object);
```

Извлечь из сессии:

```
Object object = session.getAttribute("key");
```

Можно проверить есть ли объект в сессии. Если нет, положить туда новый. Если есть, то использовать то что есть.

```
Object object = session.getAttribute("key");
if (object == null) {
    object = new Object();
    session.setAttribute("key", object);
}
```

Фремвёрки делают это всё за Вас. Вам остаётся только пометить класс объекта как внедряемый с областью видимости "для сессии" и пометить поле в сервлете.
Всего пара слов/строк вместо вон скольки.
Как это делается показывал в ответе на один из Ваших прошлых вопросов. Кратко.

Сделать класс внедряемым для сессии:

```
@SessionScoped
public class DBJointPool {
    ...
}
```

Внедрить в один сервлет:

```
public class AddUserServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Inject
    private DBJointPool db;
    ...
}
```

Внедрить в другой:

```
public class DeleteUserServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Inject
    private DBJointPool db;
    ...
}
```

Так же просто объекты привязываются к запросу. Когда нужно с каждым запросом получать новый объект.

```
@RequestScoped
public class DBJoinPool {
    ...
}
```

Comment: я до спринга пока еще не добрался а вот это прям то что доктор прописал спасибо большое.

Comment: а сохранение объекта в сессию в каком классе делать, мои сервлеты примерно равнозначны, и мне надо где-то сохранить объект в сессию `session.setAttribute("key", object);` до того как мои сервлеты будут использоваться.

Comment: @Павел вот тут как раз приходят на помощь фреймвёрки, чтобы самому не городить огород:) Срочно изучайте spring или cdi. Или внимательнее перечитайте фрагмент про проверку наличия объекта в сессии. Это должно навести на определённые мысли.